# CSS to make two divs appear parallel independent of the page's width?

Tags: css

If you try to resize the window while my page is open: http://antonpug.com/mainepark/

You will see that the images in both columns jump around, they are not always level, but because the height of the content is fluid (min-height:450; and max-height:900), and the text is not the same length, the sections end up being different sizes.

How can I ensure that the sections are either just always leveled, or perhaps all sections are of the size needed for the section with the largest amount of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column A has no idea what's going on column B.

You can either set a standard height for a section (not desirable) or write some JavaScript that will tweak the heights automatically after the window resizes.

Alternately you can re-structure the HTML so that each section has two columns instead of the entire page.